# OrientDB ETL - IllegalAccessError exception

Tags: orientdb, etl

I'm not able to make the ETL importer work.

the config file i'm using is the following

```
{
  "config": {
    "log": "debug"
  },
  "begin": [],
  "source": {
    "file": {
      "path": "/mnt/shares/Sites/store.csv"      
    }
  },
  "extractor": {
    "csv" : {
      "ignoreEmptyLines": true
    }
  },
  "transformers": [
    {
      "vertex": { 
        "class": "Store" ,
        "skipDuplicates": true
      }
    }
  ],
  "loader": {
    "orientdb": {
      "dbURL": "plocal:/usr/local/src/orientdb-community-2.2.6/databases/my_database_name",
      "dbUser": "myuser",
      "dbPassword": "mypass",
      "dbAutoCreate": false,
      "tx": false,
      "batchCommit": 1000,
      "wal" : false
    }
  },
  "end": []
}
```

and the error i'm getting is:

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalAccessError: tried to access method com.orientechnologies.common.exception.OException.(Ljava/lang/String;Ljava/lang/Throwable;)V from class com.orientechnologies.orient.etl.OETLProcessor
>       at com.orientechnologies.orient.etl.OETLProcessor.parseConfigAndParameters(OETLProcessor.java:136)
>       at com.orientechnologies.orient.etl.OETLProcessor.main(OETLProcessor.java:113)

i even have the same error if i put the config file just with the "config" entry alone ...

anyone have some ideas on the topic?

UPDATE:
the error seems to be thrown in OETLProcessor.java at the following line:

```
        final OTransformer tr = factory.getTransformer(name);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

after retrying i found the problem:
for some reason i had 2 different .jar version, and obviously the one used was the wrong one.
i had 
- ORIENTDB_HOME/LIB/orientdb-etl-2.1.3.jar
- ORIENTDB_HOME/LIB/orientdb-etl-2.2.6.jar

i just renamed the 2.1.3 one in orientdb-etl-2.1.3.jarUNUSED

and things started to work.

The next problem was that i couldn't access using the root account (there is a clear described motive on a github issue, but i'm not able to find it again...), so i created a new admin account and used that instead.

So in the end it worked.

Answer (score 0):

I tried to import this csv

```
storeid,name
1,store1
2,store2
3,store3
```

with this json

```
    {
      "config": {
        "log": "debug"
      },
      "begin": [],
      "source": {
        "file": {
          "path": "myPath/Store.csv"      
        }
      },
      "extractor": {
        "csv" : {
            "separator": ",",
            "ignoreEmptyLines": true
        }
      },
      "transformers": [
        {
          "vertex": { 
            "class": "Store" ,
            "skipDuplicates": true
          }
        }
      ],
      "loader": {
        "orientdb": {
          "dbURL": "plocal:myPath/Store",
          "dbUser": "admin",
          "dbPassword": "admin",
          "dbAutoCreate": false,
          "tx": false,
          "batchCommit": 1000,
          "wal" : false
        }
      },
      "end": []
    }
```

and it worked for me.

[image: enter code here]

Hope it helps.

Comment: Some questions:
did you use relative paths for source file and dbURL ?
was the server running? (i read someone saying that with plocal the server should not be running)
i'm starting to think that's something related to env variables, or something similar

Comment: I used a relative path and the server was stopped

Comment: nothing, i changed the path relative to the execution dir, but nothing changed... i noticed that for some reason i have 2 different .jar versions of the etl module
It looks that the exception is thrown before even reading the config file